# Custom Flv player - add features

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flvplayer

I know how to create a FLV player in FLASH - But how do I add other features in the right click menu when a visitor hovers over the player? Like my own domain name & a toggle full screen and more.

Answer (score 0):

just use the [ContextMenu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) class to add other items.

here's the first example i found using google: http://www.webdesignmo.com/blog/2008/08/20/right-click-menu-in-actionscript-3/